# Safari and ie8 not loading google fonts

Tags: fonts

i have problem with google fonts in safari the gentium font is not displayed correctly, and in ie8 the alfa font is not displayed at all.
fonts are called 'Alfa slab one' and 'Gentium Book Basic'

this is how i embed them:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alfa+Slab+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic:400italic,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and this is how i use them:

```
font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive !important;
font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif !important; font-style: italic;
```

and this is the site:

[a link](http://www.lihtne.ee/cms3.0.5/sites/seto/index.html)